# Freemarker - is nested if allowed inside else (not the common if elseif...elseif else)

Tags: freemarker

I am **not asking** about the common nesting in freemarker (which I know for sure is supported) :

```
<#if cond1> do abc
<#elseif cond2> do xxx
<#elseif cond3> do yyy
<#else> do zzz
</#if>
```

**Want to know if the below nesting is supported** in freemarker:

```
<#if cond1> do abc
<#else> 
    <#if cond-X> do xxx </#if>
    <#if cond-Y> do yyy </#if>
    <#if cond-Z> do zzz </#if>
</#if>
```

**Note that I have multiple if conditions inside the else.**

My code throws error
`Error detail: Syntax error in template "template" in line 1282, column 45: Unexpected directive, "</#if>". Check if you have a valid #if-#elseif-#else structure.`

So I suspect the latter type of nesting provided by my architect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported, and what you show is parsed successfully for me. Maybe the error is elsewhere, or you aren't looking at the template that's actually processed?

Comment: True. The issue was with a list not closed properly (actually made a typo in list closing), but freemarker unnecessarily diverted the issue to 'if' statement which was bizzare.